# Opinion regarding the book "Friendly Approach To Functional Analysis"

Tags: functional-analysis, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am interested in learning functional analysis through self study. My long-term goal is to use the concepts to grasp a better understanding of other topics e.g. optimization. My background includes linear algebra, calculus, and real analysis (I am still improving myself in the latter).

As I was looking for a book suitable for self-study, I found the following title:
"Friendly Approach To Functional Analysis" by Sasane.

I have found these reviews [MAA](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/a-friendly-approach-to-functional-analysis) and [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1786343347), which have given me a good impression of the suitability of the book for my case. Also, according to the book's author, I have the pre-requisites to go through it.

Nonetheless, I would appreciate any feedback from the community fellows about the book with respect to its suitability for self-study as well as depth-breadth of the exposition.

Thanks in advance!